# SQL: Produce a matrix to show counts for a different combinations of values

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a solution for producing a matrix such as the one proposed below in SQL?

The table below shows 100 students taking the module Cat Studies and then 52 of those took both Dog Studies and Cat Studies but only 3 took a combination of Cat Studies and Gerbil Studies.  And so on.

```
Modules         Cat Studies  Dog Studies  Gerbil Studies
Cat Studies       100             52            3
Dog Studies       52              75            45
Gerbil Studies    3               45            60
```

The input data would be

```
module             personCode
Cat Studies        1345
Cat Studies        1234
Gerbil Studies     5634
Dog Studies        9878
Gerbil Studies     5643
Dog Studies        7362
```

This source database is Oracle but we have a data warehouse on SQL server which we could load this to.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the input data that you are using.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Do a self `JOIN`, with `GROUP BY` and use `CASE` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select t1.module,
       sum(case when t2.module = 'Cat Studies' then 1 end) as "Cat Studies",
       sum(case when t2.module = 'Dog Studies' then 1 end) as "Dog Studies",
       sum(case when t2.module = 'Gerbil Studies' then 1 end) as "Gerbil Studies"
from tablename t1
  join tablename t2 on t1.personCode = t2.personCode
group by t1.module
```